# Standard ML : How to access column from list of list in standard ML

Tags: ml

Suppose I have a list of list
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
and i want to calculate the sum of the columns.
i.e The first column is [1,4,7]and its sum is 12
    Second column is [2,5,8] ans sum is 15 and so on

Is there any efficient way(with less complexity) in standard ML to do this?? Please help

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
fun transpose [] = []
  | transpose ([]::xss) = []
  | transpose xss = map hd xss :: transpose (map tl xss)

val sum = foldl op+ 0

val sumsOfColumns = map sum o transpose
```

Example use:

```
sumsOfColumns [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  (* => [12, 15, 18] *)
```

;)