# Combining a column of lists in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to essentially transpose a matrix in OCaml (without using recursion or any sort of looping)

For example, if I have the following matrix: `[[1;2];[3;4]]`,
I want to have the output of `[[1;3];[2;4]]`.

What I have done so far is break the original matrix into individual columns:

```
//function that separates into cols
let separate li =
    List.map (fun x -> [x]) li;;
```

I call this helper function from another function:

```
let trans x = 
    List.concat (List.map separate li) x;;
```

I was thinking this would combine all the columns the way I want to but rather, ended with the following output: `[[1];[2];[3];[4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I question whether your `separate` function separates the matrix into columns. Here's what I see:

```
# let separate li = List.map (fun x -> [x]) li;;
val separate : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# List.map separate [[1;2];[3;4]];;
- : int list list list = [[[1]; [2]]; [[3]; [4]]]
```

I don't see columns, I just see that you've put each matrix element into its own list.

To get the first column you could try this:

```
# List.map List.hd [[1;2]; [3;4]];;
- : int list = [1; 3]
```

If you use `List.tl` rather than `List.hd` you get the remainders of the rows. Maybe you can use a fold to apply this repeatedly and collect up the results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of lists is rectangular, [this Standard ML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342394/standard-ml-how-to-access-column-from-list-of-list-in-standard-ml) translates to OCaml as such:

```
let rec transpose xss =
    match xss with
        | [] -> []
        | []::_ -> []
        | _ -> List.map List.hd xss :: transpose (List.map List.tl xss)
```

It extracts the first column (`List.map List.hd xss`) and recursively combines it with the extraction of the remaining columns, after having removed the already extracted column (`List.map List.tl xss`).

The explicit recursion that still remains in this function cannot easily be replaced by mapping / folding, since those would address one row at a time, where the recursion scheme above addresses (a part of) all rows at once. You might have more luck with [*unfolding / anamorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism):

```
let rec unfold f a =
    match f a with
    | Some (b, a') -> b :: unfold f a'
    | None -> []

val unfold : ('a -> ('b * 'a) option) -> 'a -> 'b list = <fun>
```

where `'a` could be the gradual reduction of your input row matrix, and `'b` the matrix columns:

```
let transpose =
    unfold (function
            | [] -> None
            | []::_ -> None
            | m -> Some (List.map List.hd m, List.map List.tl m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to [sshine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36675531/15261315): the transposition of a list of lists can be done in a tail-recursive manner.

```
let transpose lst = 
  let rec aux lst acc =
    match lst with 
    | [] | []::_ -> List.rev acc
    | (x::xs)::ys -> aux (xs :: List.map List.tl ys) ((x :: List.map List.hd ys) :: acc)
  in
  try 
    Some (aux lst []) 
  with 
  | Failure _ -> None;;
val transpose : 'a list list -> 'a list list option = <fun>
```

It's then straightforward to modify this to generate a [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html), allowing lazy iteration over columns rather than eagerly creating a list of all of the columns. Of course, with this approach we can't know if the list of lists is non-rectangular until we actually get to the irregularity.

```
# let transpose_list_as_seq lst =
    let rec aux lst () =
      match lst with
      | [] | []::_ -> Seq.Nil
      | (x::xs)::ys -> 
        Seq.Cons (
          x :: List.map List.hd ys, 
          aux @@ xs :: List.map List.tl ys
        )
    in
    aux lst;;
val transpose_list_as_seq : 'a list list -> 'a list Seq.t = <fun>
# [[4;5;6]; [1;2;3]] 
  |> transpose_list_as_seq 
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list list = [[4; 1]; [5; 2]; [6; 3]]
# [[4;5]; [1]] 
  |> transpose_list_as_seq 
  |> List.of_seq;;
Exception: Failure "tl".
```

But we can handle this by moving the exception handling into the function and handling the `Failure` exception `List.hd` or `List.tl` can create by returning `Seq.Nil`.

```
# let transpose_list_as_seq lst =
    let rec aux lst () =
      match lst with
      | [] | []::_ -> Seq.Nil
      | (x::xs)::ys -> 
        try
          Seq.Cons (
            x :: List.map List.hd ys, 
            aux @@ xs :: List.map List.tl ys
          )
        with
        | Failure _ -> Seq.Nil
    in
    aux lst;;
val transpose_list_as_seq : 'a list list -> 'a list Seq.t = <fun>
# [[4;5;6]; [1;2;3]] 
  |> transpose_list_as_seq 
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list list = [[4; 1]; [5; 2]; [6; 3]]
# [[4;5]; [1]] 
  |> transpose_list_as_seq 
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list list = [[4; 1]]
```