# Generating list of integers in OCaml without recursion

Tags: list, ocaml, fold

How can I use one of the fold functions to generate a list of integers from 0 to a value n-1? I'm confused about how to get fold_right to return a list rather than returning just an accumulated value.

This is for a helper function that I'm trying to define to solve a larger problem. Here is my attempt:

-I know the base case has to be a list containing only zero, because I do not want to add anything less than zero.
-I know that I need to decrement the value n so that I can put numbers from n-1 to 0 in the list.

```
let buildList n = 
  let ibuildList elem list =
    list@[n-1]
  in List.fold_right ibuildList n [0];;
```

But I get an error underscoring "n" in the last line saying that the expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a list. Isn't n an integer that I'm turning into a list via [n-1]? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very sorry, I missed at least one step of the reasoning.

A fold is for traversing a collection. Since you want to generate a list and you just have `n`, not a collection, you can't really use fold in any reasonable way. In fact, what you want to do is more like an unfold. I.e., you want to unfold your `n` into a list.

It's easy to write this function, but not easy to write it using a fold.

Here's an implementation of unfold in OCaml:

```
let rec unfold_right f init =
    match f init with
    | None -> []
    | Some (x, next) -> x :: unfold_right f next
```

Here's how to use `unfold_right` to generate a list of ints:

```
let range n =
    let irange x = if x > n then None else Some (x, x + 1) in
    unfold_right irange 1
```

Here's how it looks when you run `range`:

```
# range 0;;
- : int list = []
# range 8;; 
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]
# range 5;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Comment: Could you please post a couple examples of accumulated values being stuff other than just an integer?

Comment: I added two examples; I hope at least one of them is helpful :-)

Comment: Ok been playing around with code. Tiny bit confused. I updated my initial question with some code in it and the issue I'm facing. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think through to the end of your problem. I apologize. I started over with a better answer.

Comment: You say it's easy to write this function, and I can do it with recursion, but I'm preparing for a test and I won't be able to use recursion on it. (trying to get us to use higher order functions.)

Comment: You can use unfold, I added example code. Not sure if this helps for your test.

Comment: @jonnyd42: Another example that isn't just an integer: [unfolding used for transposing matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36675531/235908)

Comment: @jonnyd42 If it's just for a test where you are required to use higher order functions, you can use `Array` functionality, e.g. `let makelist n = Array.init n (fun x -> x) |> Array.to_list`. For more practical use cases, various standard library extensions (such as Batteries, Containers, or Core) have a native `List.init` function, which is missing from the normal `List` module.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative version, using the standard [Stream](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html) module:

```
(* an infinite stream of natural numbers, starting from 0 *)
let nats =
  let rec nats_from n = [< 'n; nats_from (n + 1) >]  (* extra syntax *)
  in nats_from 0

(* the first n natural numbers: [0; n-1] *)
let range n = Stream.npeek n nats
```

The piece `[< 'n; nats_from (n + 1) >]` represents a *lazy* list with `n` as its head and the next natural numbers as its tail. `Stream.npeek n stream` consumes the first `n` elements of `stream` and returns them as a list.

Tests with [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop):

```
utop # #load "dynlink.cma";; (* you need these to work with *) 
utop # #load "camlp4o.cma";; (* the Stream's syntactic extension *)

utop # range 1;;
- : int list = [0]    

utop # range 5;;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]

utop # range 10;;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
```

If you'd like to compile it, use the following commands (you need to use the camplp4o preprocessor):

```
$ ocamlc -pp camlp4o <filename>.ml
```

or

```
$ ocamlopt -pp camlp4o <filename>.ml
```