# How to form a matrix list of list using OCaml List Modules only?

Tags: list, matrix, ocaml, transpose, higher-order-functions

I was wondering how to form a matrix using O'Caml

I've formed a normal list from a list of tuples that indicate the index and the element via:

```
  List.map (fun (idx, x) -> x ) list
```

I wanted to do this for a matrix without using recursion or loops. Just higher-order functions and List.module

(Context: I'm trying to transpose a matrix given a matrix)

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to do what you say. It ignores the elements and makes a list of the indices. It's not clear what you're asking for with regard to a matrix. Are you saying you'll have a list of triples (index1, index2, element)? Are you guaranteeing that the indices will start at 0 (say) and will be dense? Will they be in order?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I just fixed it, it was a typo. My bad. And yes, I'm trying to get a list of triples (index1, index2, element). My approach to trying to transpose the matrix is 1. Attaching a flag or so to each element as a number that represents the index it is (via mapi?) 2. Collapsing the matrix into a big list of tuples that give information of the location (via flatten) 3. Iterate through the list of tuples and assemble a matrice using @ to reform the matrix

Comment: Someone just a few days ago asked [how to transpose a matrix represented as a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672807/combining-a-column-of-lists-in-ocaml).

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach will work, though it might not be the fastest method.

There's no simple function to construct a list (or a list of lists) from a set of indices and elements. It's hard to make a clean and simple definition of a function like that because of all the values the indices could have (duplicates, missing values, out of order, etc.).

I'd say the missing step would be to sort the list of triples into the desired order. Since there's a sort function in the List module, this is presumably allowed by your limitations.

In essence, the original order sorts by the first index then the second. So to get the transpose you want to sort by the second index then the first.

After you have the right order you can use List.fold_left or List.fold_right to assemble your final list of lists.

Here's a function that reformats a list into groups of threes using List.fold_left. This isn't the function you want, but it might be close:

```
let bythrees l =
    let iby (cur, prev, n) x =
        if n mod 3 = 2 then ([], (x :: cur) :: prev, n + 1)
        else (x :: cur, prev, n + 1)
    in
    let (_, res, _) = List.fold_left iby ([], [], 0) l in
    res
```

Here's how it looks when you run it:

```
# bythrees [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];;
- : int list list = [[9; 8; 7]; [6; 5; 4]; [3; 2; 1]]
```

The output still needs some work, but this shows you can make a list of lists this way.